# root.listFiles() return null

Tags: android

I created an activity which will recursively scan all the files in a particular directory. For this, I used the File object return by

```
'Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()'
```

as the starting point.

Now the issue is, on calling files.listFiles() on this object, I am getting a null value. I check the return value of 'Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()' and it is '/storage/emulated/0'. I have also checked and made sure that there is a file inside this directory. But I am unable to understand why it is returning a null value.

I am using an inbuild android emulator for testing

Can someone please help me here

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? "The result is null if this file is not a directory"

Comment: isDirectory() method returns true for 'Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()' file object

Comment: I'm sure it does. I'm simply explaining why the method returns null. :)  I'm not sure why they contradict each other

Comment: Does your app have permission to read external storage?

Comment: Do you have required permission set?
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score 1):

This may solves the issue:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

> If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target
>   SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the
>   manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while
>   the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and
>   the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user
>   denies a permission request.